# How can I get Tomcat to serve external JSP's

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I have a `war` that also needs to serve `jsp`'s from alternative external directories. In `weblogic` this is achieved with virtual directory mappings.

Is there a clean way to achieve this with `Tomcat`?

Comment: Dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775700/jsp-files-in-external-directory

Comment: Dup2? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195437/loading-jsp-pages-from-custom-sources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends of the case:

- If the entire context is in an external directory, you can have a context xml file that points at that directory(docBase="/external/directory")
- If you have an open deploy (not war file) on any unix system, you can have a symbolic link to the external directory. Notice that redeploys may ruin this.
- If you want just a single directory and doesn't want to (or can't) use symbolic links, the the answer is no.