# Using Spring Web. There's a way to use views path in AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, amazon-web-services, view, amazon-s3

I'm using a normal view resolver, like:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/presentation/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

There's a way to use this resolver to point to some S3 bucket external to application?

Comment: Do you mean jsps external to application? Or you want to redirect to a url?

Comment: External to application... Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195437/loading-jsp-pages-from-custom-sources